Как вывести модальное окно alert() выбрав соответствующую позицию (<option>) в теге <select> по содержимому (по тексту)
Проблема в следующем: нужно сделать что-то вроде опросника с помощью , причем содержимое двух последующим меняется от выбора  в предыдущем . При выборе пользователем нужного  по его содержимому в последнем  должно появляться модальное окно alert() с описанием. Последняя часть у меня застопорилась (я запутался). Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с последней частью.(jquery в HTML подключен).
HTML:
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
      <select class="form-select" id="list1">
        <option selected>Вы являетесь:</option>
        <option value="1">Физическое лицо</option>
        <option value="2">Юридическое лицо</option>                             
      </select>
  </div>                        
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <select class="form-select" id="list2" disabled>
      <option selected></option>                                        
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <select class="form-select" id="list3" disabled>
      <option selected></option>                                            
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

JS:
var ohran1=[];
var ohran2=[[],[],[]];
var ohrana1;

var lst1 = document.getElementById("list1");
var lst2 = document.getElementById("list2");
var lst3 = document.getElementById("list3");

ohran1[0]=["1","2","3"];
ohran1[1]=["4","5","6"];
ohran2[0][0]=["7","8","9"];
ohran2[0][1]=["10","11","12"];
ohran2[0][2]=["13","14","15"];
ohran2[1][0]=["16","17","18"];
ohran2[1][1]=["19","20","21"];
ohran2[1][2]=["22","23","24"];

lst1.onchange = function() {
  lst2.disabled = false;
    ohrana1 = this.value-1;
    if (ohrana1 != -1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < ohran1[ohrana1].length; i++) {
            lst2.innerHTML+='<option value="'+(i+1)+'">'+ohran1[ohrana1][i]+'</option>';
        }
    } else {
        lst2.disabled = true;
        lst3.disabled = true;
    }
}

lst2.onchange = function() {
    lst3.disabled = false;
    var mc = this.value - 1;
    if (mc != -1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < ohran2[ohrana1][mc].length; i++) {
            lst3.innerHTML+='<option value="'+(i+1)+'">'+ohran2[ohrana1][mc][i]+'</option>';
        }
    } else {
        lst3.disabled=true;
    }
}
    
$("#list3").on("change", function () {        //вот здесь
    if($(this).option.innerText === "1") {     //у меня и 
        alert('Привет!!!');                   //проблемка
    }
});


Вместо:
$("#list3").on("change", function () {        
    if($(this).option.innerText === "1") {     
        alert('Привет!!!');                   
    }
});

надо использовать:
$(document).on('change','#list3',function () {
    var txt1 = ($('option:selected', this).text());
    if ((txt1 === "1")) {
        alert("привет!!!");
        
    }
});

